# How build Xamarin against older version of iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to build my Xamarin Forms app for the Apple store using Xamarin Studio on my MacBook. This worked fine until recently.

The only options available to me on the SDK version dropdown on the iOS Build tab are Default and **8.3**. If I build using either of these and try to upload to the store I get the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90068: "This bundle is invalid. The value provided for the
>   key MinimumOSVersion '8.3' is not acceptable."

I guess this is due to updating all Xamarin and Xcode components to their latest versions recently.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the 8.2 SDK back.

I tried downloading the **iOS 8.2 Simulator** from `Xcode > Preferences > Downloads` but that doesn't seem to have added anything in the Xamarin SDK version dropdown.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're confusing the SDK version used to build your app with and the minimum iOS version your app requires.

It's perfectly possible to build an app using the iOS 8.3 SDK and target iOS 5.1.1 for instance.

You need to set the minimum iOS version for your app instead of changing the SDK version; this is done in the project's iOS Application options, by setting `Deployment Target` to your app's minimum iOS version.

Comment: Thanks for this - it worked well. It's a shame this is not explained better in the Xamarin docs. I spent most of a morning trying to figure this out. Most of the posts I found when searching were others with the same issue.

Comment: This was in Info.plist for me, not iOS Application properties.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did to resolve the issue:

- Right click on the `.iOS` project > Options
- Set `Build > iOS Build > Link behaviour` to `Link Framework SDKs Only`.