# Versions Android , IOS and UWP in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In the Xamarin Forms I can set minimal supported and target version of the Android what I want , but I can not find this for IOS . Does is exist ?
 For UWP I found minimal version Windows 10(10.0;10240) . It posibil to set less version , and I need this ? Does is exist devices to day on the less version Windows ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46478139/6060754 -check this

Comment: @Srusti Thakkar thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the iOS version by going to your iOS project, right-clicking on *Info.plist*, click *Open With...*, and then select *iOS Manifest Editor (Default)*. There you can set your deployment target in the *Application* tab. This will edit the `<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>` value in *Info.plist*.

Comment: Thank you @sme ! I have only one version 10.3 and I not see in my VS installer how can I larged list of the versions . It possible to get more versions for IOS in Xamarin Forms ?

Comment: @sml I set by hand version 8 . In the drop down list is nothing . It's correct this way ? Cause I can put any number and it will work in VS .

Comment: Yes, in my project I set it to 8.0

Comment: **sme** what version of SDK I need for UWP for that support Windows 8.1 ? For exemple windows fall creators update (10.0;16299) will support ?

Comment: Windows 8.1 isnt supported anymore, only UWP is now

Comment: Ok , but if I run UWP from Xamarin Forms with windows fall creators update (10.0;16299) in cellphone with OS Windows 8.1 it will work ?

Comment: It wont work, the phone will need to also be running Windows 10

Comment: Ok thank you **sme** ! What can I do to make available support windows 8.1 ? It possible ?

Comment: I think the only way is to use an older version of Xamarin.Forms (I wouldn't recommend it though), although I can't remember which is the last version of Xamarin.Forms to support Windows 8.1