# What versions of iOS are supported by Xamarin.iOS 10.14 / .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, .net-standard

What is the **oldest** version of iOS that I can write code for using .NET Standard 2.0 which, according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)  needs Xamarin.iOS 10.14 which, according to [*its* documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.10/)  needs macOS High Sierra to code. But I can't find which version of iOS can we develop *for*, there.

**EDIT**

I'm not asking if I can code for iOS 11 with it. I'm asking about iOS 7, 6, 5, ...

Comment: See also [How build Xamarin against older version of iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477977/xamarin-forms-ios-minimum-supported-version) and [Xamarin Forms - IOS minimum supported version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46477977/xamarin-forms-ios-minimum-supported-version)

Answer (score 0):

From [Xamarin.iOS 10.14 release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.14/):

> Requirements
>
> - The latest features and API requires Xcode 8.3 and the bundled iOS, tvOS and watchOS SDKs;
> - Apple Xcode 8.3 requires a Mac running OSX 10.12 (Sierra) or newer;

To check what iOS simulator version can be downloaded in Xcode open `Xcode > Preferences > Components`

With Xcode Version 8.3 the oldest iOS simulator listed is iOS 8.1 Simulator:

[image]

Lowest [deployment target](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/9.3/#/dev110756139) in Xcode 8.3 is 8.0:

> The deployment target specifies the lowest operating system version that your app can run on.

[image]

See also Xamarin [System Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/requirements), [Xamarin.iOS Installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/index) and [Xcode Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html).

Lowest deployment target in Visual Studio 2017 15.6.0 is 6.0:
[image]

The default installed version of Xamarin.iOS in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6
is [Xamarin.iOS 11.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#xamarin).