# How do I build an iOS xamarin app for an older SDK version?

Tags: ios, xamarin, sdk

Currently SDK 15.4 is the only available option to build my iOS Xamarin project with in the "iOS Build -> SDK Version" drop-down field of project options.  It looks like that SDK is located in folder /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework.  If I wanted to instead compile for SDK 13.4... how would I go about doing this?  Do I just have to download the SDK 13.4 to that folder or is there more to it?  And where would I download this older SDK from?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no reason to. Using latest, you can **target** whatever version you want. [How build Xamarin against older version of iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688992/how-build-xamarin-against-older-version-of-ios-sdk)

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio for Mac, you can install different Xamarin.iOS packages whatever you want however it only works on Mac.You can go to [Xamarin.iOS github repo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios) and download the pkg file ,install on mac.

Also,as @Steve suggested,the `Deployment Target` setting is used to select the minimum required version of the operating system on which your application will run. This is set in your project's `Info.plist` file. You should pick the minimum version that has all the APIs that you need to run your application.

You could refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/compiling-for-different-devices?tabs=windows) for more details.